# Probability Distribution 22

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

X1 ∼ N(µ = 2, σ = 2
X2 ∼ N(µ = 1, σ = 4
X3 ∼ N(µ = −4, σ= 3
X1, X2, and X3 be independent and Y = (X1 + 2X2 + X3)^2

Determine P(Y > E(Y ))

My solution:

I got the value of E(Y) as 53

So, P((X1+2x2+x3)^2 >53 )

Can I get some hints on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the distribution of $W:=X_1+2X_2+X_3$ (they are a sum of independent normals).

Now use the fact that for $a\geq 0$, $\{W:W^2>a\}= \{W:W<-\sqrt a\}\cup \{W:W>\sqrt a\}.$

Comment: a is the distribution of W?

Comment: $a$ is the mean of $Y$ in your setup

Comment: a=53 in this case, right?

Comment: I would suggest showing how you got that in your question

Comment: E[Y] = E[X1^2] + 4 E[X2^2] + E[X3^2] = VAR(X1) - (E(X1))^2 + 4 [VAR(X2)- (E(X2))^2 + VAR(X3)- (E(X3))^2 = 4-4 + 4(16-1) +9-16 =53

Comment: Try $\text{Var(W)}=E[W^2]-(E[W])^2\implies E[Y]=E[W^2]=\text{Var(W)}+(E[W])^2$ where $W$ is defined as above