# Evaluating the probability of a Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, order-statistics

$X_1 ∼ N(µ = 2, σ = 2), X_2 ∼ N(µ = 1, σ = 4), X_3 ∼ N(µ = −4, σ= 3):$ $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3$ be independent and $Y = (X_1 + 2X_2 + X_3)^2.$

Determine $P(Y > E(Y)).$

My solution: I got the value of $E(Y) = 77$ and $Var(Y) = 11858.$

So, this means $Y \sim N(77,11858).$ (Is this right?)
and $P(Y> E(Y))$ becomes $P(Y>77).$

Comment: The exact same question was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369540/probability-distribution-22/4369543#4369543

Comment: Do you think mine is the right approach?

Comment: Did you see my answer to the other post?

Comment: I got some hints mine W is coming to 0 as your previous answer and a is coming as 77. Now what will be the next steps?

Comment: $W$ is a random variable, so I am not sure how you can get that it is zero. But you should be able to find the distribution of $W$ (including mean and var).

Answer (score 0):

*Comment:* It seems you are now on the right track.
Consider the following simulation, which should
be sufficiently accurate to see if any results are wrong.
With sample sizes of a million, most means, standard deviations, and probabilities should be
accurate to 2 or 3 significant digits. (Variances have
squared units and so would not be accurate to so many digits.)
Because $Y$ is normal with mean $0,$ the distribution
of $Y^2$ is a multiple of a chi-squared distribution.

```
set.seed(2021)
m = 10^6
x1 = rnorm(m, 2, 2)
x2 = rnorm(m, 1, 4)
x3 = rnorm(m, -4, 3)
s = x1 + 2*x2 + x3
mean(s); sd(s)
[1] 0.007333673   # aprx E(S)
[1] 8.775375      # aprx SD(S)
y = s^2
mu.y = mean(y);  mu.y
[1] 77.00718      # aprx E(Y)
sd(y)
[1] 108.9997      # aprx SD(Y)
mean(y > mu.y)
[1]  0.317496     # aprx P[Y > E(Y)]
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(s, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(s), sd(s)), add=T, col="orange")
 hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  abline(v = mu.y, col="orange", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Could you please tell how to find P(Y> E(Y)) analytically?

Comment: Because $Y$ is normal with mean $0,$ the distribution of $Y^2$ is a multiple of a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom.